# How to i add a gradient to particles, normal to the emitters surface?

Tags: materials, particles, procedural

This is a very special question i'd imagine ;)

I have a base shape, that uses a particle system with pyramids on it.

[image]

Im triyng to add a gradient to the pyramid-spikes.

This efffect by itself can be easily done in a material for the particle.

[image]
[image]

BUT: The fade on the pyramids will only be a part of a more complex material for the whole shape.

[image]

Currently i convert the particles into a mesh and then join them into one object to achieve this.

I currently have no way to achieve the gradient on each pyramid, but also have control over the material of the whole shape.

So im emulating it with this node setup, someone shared with me.
[image]

But this only works partially, since i dont have a sperical shape.

Any ideas on how to solve this problem are well appreciated.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: dynamic paint proximity to the emitter mesh might be worth a try.

Comment: What effect are you actually looking for on the whole shape,( ignoring the particles, for a moment,)  that you're only partially achieving with the gradient setup that you show here?

Comment: i will add a iridescent effect to the whole thing sort of like this: https://78.media.tumblr.com/02780d0cb02185243e6fe4df2602041f/tumblr_pbikmov0ad1wwb2aso2_r1_400.gif

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Gradient texture upon Generate coordinates

To assign a gradient texture to the single particle object you can use the built-in node available for cycles. You can control the gradient with a color ramp node as well.

The tricky part in your setup is that you would like to access the data of a different mesh that doesn't belong to the particle. One possible way is to take advantage of the Object option in the Texture Coordinate node.

You didn't share your setup for the colored shader (the one you show with particles baked and joined), so I'll assume by guessing that you are using the Generate texture coordinate of the object. We can't access that data, but we can try to transform the Object's texture coordinate from an empty object.

In the following example I'm using the Mapping node to translate the empty's (which was created in the same location of the object's origin) coordinates.

[image]

An altenative would be to simply move the empty in one of the corner of the object's bounding box and scale it appropriately:

[image]

The following image sequence is showing the node in action. The shape on the right is the mesh with particles baked with a shader showing the Generated coordinates to use as reference.

[image]

[image]

*Note: accessing data from other objects may not be possible for all the attributes. Object's texture from another object can only provide location, rotation and scale of the object.*

Comment: The "from dubli" looks very very promising. i'll try it out and get back with results. Thanks so much already.

Comment: It's just a trick that works for this case, don't expect to ba able to do thing much different than what shown. Also it is probably not necessary the "From Dupli" option, you could get the same effect by playing with the vectors... it's just easier to understand in my opinion.

Comment: I have no idea what im doing wrong but it wont work. i cant get the from dubli to work. How do you get the particle-material onto the particles ? Cause the material setting in the particle is greyed out as soon as i use objects or a group.  You write that on the left has the particles applied ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant "on the right", the one who stays still. I edted the answer. The material is applied to the partcle object that ios being duplicated (the little pyramid on the top in this case, you cen see it also in the image sequence).

Comment: ok thanks for clearing that up. But i have no idea how to get the from dubli to work. I even tried a very basic test in a new file. Could you share the blendfile with me ?

Comment: Forget the "from duply" option and focus on the external object. I've added a blendfile you can inspect.

Comment: This is how it looks for me: https://imgur.com/a/Flkf1Rf i have no idea whats happening

Comment: You have to go in Rendered view. Not all the node features are supported in Material view yet .

Comment: ohhh god. that has been my problem all along. Thanks again for your patience